# How does ASP.NET know which event to fire during a postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

During a postback, the `__EVENTTARGET` form variable holds the `name of the control` which issued the postback. How does ASP.NET know which event to fire for that control if the control supports several server side events?

Comment: are u asking WHY its doing what its doing, or HOW u can get this to work ?

Comment: None of these. If a control supports several events, how does asp.net know which to fire? Just passing the control id in __EVENTTARGET can't be enough.

Answer (score 5):

As Wiktor mentions, many of the controls in ASP.Net have already been built for you to be used in certain ways; the button click, the text change, the selected index changed - these controls have been built to do certain things, [which is why they work the way they do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx).

From the documentation:

> Because most ASP.NET server control events require a round trip to the
>   server for processing, they can affect the performance of a page.
>   Therefore, server controls offer a limited set of events, usually only
>   click-type events. Some server controls support change events. For
>   example, the CheckBox Web server control raises a CheckedChanged event
>   in server code when the user clicks the box. Some server controls
>   support more abstract events. For example, the Calendar Web server
>   control raises a SelectionChanged event that is a more abstract
>   version of a click event.

You can, of course, write your own client side controls, but this requires a lot more work. The article [Server Event Handling in ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xax2hw3x.aspx) discusses this. To summarise, though, the important section is implementing [RaisePostBackEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.raisepostbackevent.aspx)

If you want to provide multiple events, then you vary the event argument sent to this method from the client, and raise the appropriate server side event. This can be as simple as an if statement. A basic example would be having two client side javascript events, each of which might call:

```
__doPostBack(controlId, 'superclick');

__doPostBack(pageId, 'superchange');
```

And then, in your post back event handler, call the required server side event based on the passed argument. A simple RaisePostBackEvent server side handler would then look something like:

```
  public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument){

     if(eventArgument == "superclick")
     {
        OnSuperClick(this, new EventArgs());
     }

     if(eventArgument == "superchange")
     {
        OnSuperChange(this, new EventArgs());
     }         

  }
```

Comment: RaisePostBackEvent contains two arguments http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.raisepostbackevent.aspx

Comment: @PankajGarg That's Page.RaisePostBackEvent. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.raisepostbackevent.aspx as referenced in the answer. Alternatively, you can be lazy and just look in Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"] when posting back.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging with the aid of an HTTP sniffer such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) can help here. Broadly, **the event details are in the `__EVENTARGUMENT` form field**. How that data is unpacked is an implementation detail of the particular control.

For example, drop a `TreeView` onto a form, and hook up its `TreeNodeCollapsed`, `TreeNodeExpanded`, and `SelectedNodeChanged` events. You will see that *expanding or collapsing* a node results in a postback with something like `tnode_text` in `__EVENTARGUMENT`; whereas *selecting* a node results in a postback with something like `snode_text` in `__EVENTARGUMENT`. My guess is that `t` stands for "toggle", and `s` for "select", but I haven't dug into the source to check.

(Incidentally, just saying "toggle" is good enough for both expand and collapse, since the `..._ExpandState` form variable holds details of the expand state of all nodes, it looks like).

Answer (score 1):

To handle postback ASP.NET server control must implement [`IPostBackEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) interface. This interface has a single method `void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)` which processes an event raised when a form is posted to the server.

This method is responsible for raising the server side events of the control. The only parameter here is `eventArgument` *which is used to differentiate the type of event* if necessary (like a `GridView`).

E.g. `Button` control raises both `Click` and `Command` events. `GridView` parses command name from the event argument parameter, and fires a necessary event for the command.

You could use .NET decompiler (I used excellent [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for this) to look through the implementation of `RaisePostBackEvent` method for the standard ASP.NET controls.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in case of controls which hold a **single** value, passed in form's data, there's no need room for any doubts - `TextBox` can be **changed**, `DropDownList` can have its value **changed** etc.

In fact, such controls usually have only one event triggered from the client side, other events are for the server side pipeline (`DataBinding`, `DataBound`, `Init`, `Load` etc.)

Any composite control, on the other side, can use `__EVENTARGUMENTS` to provide additional parameters to the server so that the actual event can be determined and dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to handle a postback event in your control, you would be Implementing [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y35b7zf3.aspx) interface. The framework would call IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent method which accepts eventArgument. Based on the event argument you can raise various other custom events.

Other Control events like Init, Load etc will be called by the framework automatically, irrespective of whether the control can handle postback events.